# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SchemaFactory that implements the schema language specified

Tags: java, xml, wsdl, schema

I am getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SchemaFactory that implements the schema language specified by: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance could be loaded
>       at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(SchemaFactory.java:204)
>       at MAIN.SchemaImport3.validateXMLSchema(SchemaImport3.java:74)
>       at MAIN.SchemaImport3.main(SchemaImport3.java:62)

Here is my code:

```
URL source;
source = new URL(schemaList.getDocumentBaseURI());
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(
                         XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI`:

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance( 
    XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI 
);
```

The URI "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" (value of the `XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI`) is not an XML schema language by itself, but a property (or feature, or additional mechanism, if you like) of the XML Schema.

The proper name for the W3C XML Schema is "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" (value of the `XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI`).

Comment: I would like to underline that using `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` works with http **but not with https**